# @model and @html data are marked as errors in .NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, api, https, asp.net-core-mvc

When I start writing Views in .Net Core MVC I always get such kind of error and model is evaluated as null. When I run just backend of this application everything works fine. I think I configured HttpClient correctly and do not understand where these errors come from.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3E9Z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVzwL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVzwL.png)

Comment: Hi @T_12345,Try to clean the solution and rebuild the solution.And for your asp-for tag helper does not highlight,be sure you have added `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried all of that but it did not work. Then I updated Visual Studio and everything got fixed.